# In Play! application base document fields are not persisted to mongo db (reactive mongo plugin)

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have Play 2.3 appliction with reactive mongo plugin.
I have base document:

```
trait TemporalDocument {
  val created: Option[DateTime] = Some(new DateTime())
  val updated: Option[DateTime] = Some(new DateTime())
}
```

and one of the concrete document:

```
case class User(name: String) extends TemporalDocument

object User{
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
}
```

So when I persist it to mongo db using reactive mongo plugin only name is persisted, created/updated fields are not.

My repository looks like:

```
trait MongoDocumentRepository[T <: TemporalDocument] extends ContextHolder {

  private val db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db

  def insert(document: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): Future[String] = {
    collection.insert(document).map {
      lastError => lastError.toString
    } recover {
      case e: Exception => sys.error(e.getMessage)
    }
  }

  private def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)

  implicit object BSONDateTimeHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDateTime, DateTime] {
    def read(time: BSONDateTime) = new DateTime(time.value)

    def write(jdtime: DateTime) = BSONDateTime(jdtime.getMillis)
  }
}
```

Problem is that I will have many documents extended from base document and I do not want each time init those dates and probably some other fields. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we can halve the surface-area of the problem; Reactive Mongo and/or the Play Reactive Mongo Plugin are not relevant here, it's [Play's JSON macros](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) that build the appropriate JSON structures (or not, in this case) that are responsible.

If I set up a `TemporalDocument` and `User` as in your code, and then write it out:

```
val user = User("timmy")

println(Json.toJson(user))
```

I get:

```
{"name":"timmy"}
```

I haven't looked into it, but I suspect this is because the `created` and `updated` fields don't appear in the "field list" of the `User` case class.

If I rework your code a little bit like this:

```
trait TemporalDocument {
  val created: Option[DateTime]
  val updated: Option[DateTime]
}

case class User(
                name: String,
                val created: Option[DateTime] = Some(new DateTime()),
                val updated: Option[DateTime] = Some(new DateTime())) 
                extends TemporalDocument
```

Then the same test code gets the desired behaviour from play-json:

```
{"name":"timmy","created":1410930805042,"updated":1410930805071}
```

Comment: You don't even need `val`s in `User` constructor because case class constructor parameters are public `val`s by default